# Users got deleted after adding a user in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I added an user in SVN using this command 
"httpasswd -cm /etc/httpd/users/svn-auth-conf username"
but after adding this user all other users which were present in that svn-auth-conf file got erased and they unable to login now. Can anyone please help.

Comment: welcome to club of programmers, version dependency falling!

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

`htpasswd` did exactly what you told it to do. From the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html)

> -c
>
> Create the passwdfile. If passwdfile already exists, it is rewritten and truncated. This option cannot be combined with the -n option.
>
> -m
>
> Use MD5 encryption for passwords. This is the default (since version 2.2.18).

You told it to overwrite the existing file with new contents, and use MD5 for the hashing algorithm for the new password you're adding.

I hope you've got a recent backup somewhere.

Comment: I don't have the recent backup. Is there any way i can get that old file back? Also users had some data saved using old login so if that logins don't exist is there a chance that there data also doesn't exist?

Comment: Data committed to your repository isn't lost, but if you weren't backing up that `svn-auth-conf` file, you'll have to re-create the credentials for those user accounts. Followup question you need to answer for yourself and your organization: Why don't you have backups?